# AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'fast_executemany'

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift, pandas-to-sql

AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'fast_executemany'

to_sql() is too slow. so trying to resolve the problem. but when I run the following code I am getting :-

> AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute
>   'fast_executemany'

```
@event.listens_for(conn, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
        cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 4):

use insert with tuples it around 200 time faster than `executemany` in  `psycopg`

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in tup)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

its equivalent of

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: I have 13 columns and 900K  rows in csv format. I am reading it with pandas. when I run the above code i am geting the mentioned error. I am new to mogrify().  would you plz make your point in detail? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15276

Comment: cut it by batches 1k rows and iterate by them @RAVIVERMA